# BASH: How do i cache result of lolcat in variable and print it later?

Tags: linux, bash

Is it possible to cache or save the result of lolcat in a variable and print the result out later like so:

```
RESULT=$(echo mytext | lolcat);
echo $RESULT
```

The result is missing color formatting.

Comment: Quotes are important. `echo $RESULT` and `echo "$RESULT"` are two different things.

Comment: `lolcat` apparently detects that its standard output is not the terminal, and does not emit the codes that the terminal would interpret as instructions to change color.

Comment: As for color, that's probably `lolcat` checking whether its output is to a TTY. You'll need to check its documentation to see how to override that.

Comment: ...and btw, all-caps names are used by variables with meaning to the operating system or shell -- see POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html -- while lowercase variable names are reserved for application use; sticking to that namespace prevents overwriting a variable with meaning to the system by mistake.

Comment: Check for a `--force` option for lolcat

Comment: thank you guys for your input ! really appreciated ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lolcat` checks whether the output is going to a terminal. When you use command substitution, the output goes to a pipe, so it doesn't output color change codes.

Use the `--force` option to override this. And quote the variable to prevent whitespace from being collapsed.

```
result=$(echo mytext | lolcat --force)
echo "$result"
```

Comment: wow and the quotes really make a difference... whose result can be seen when the text is really long and wraps. thanks for pointing it out.